# Importing/threading in python

Tags: python, multithreading, import, pygame

My project:

- A GUI in pygame which has a grid of buttons
- A games loader
- A number of games that all need to work with the GUI

all in separate .py files

The application loader should start the GUI, the user clicks a button on the GUI which makes the games loader load a particular game, the user then interacts with the game logic by clicking some other buttons on the GUI and game state is also displayed on the GUI.

I am unsure how to structure this in python, as the games loader should import the GUI, but does the GUI then need to import the games loader to call the method to load a particular game? And similar interaction with the game file?

The GUI is an option that can be chosen, as I have hardware that will perform the same functions and they can also work alongside each other.

Its kind of like all three components need to be able to call functions from each other, but import only allows this to be one way. Is there a way to make import act like the different files are all part of the same file? Instead of them importing each other?

I've tried loads of different things, imports, threads etc, but can't get anything to work, any help is much appreciated

Sorry for the poorly worded question.

Answer (score 0):

Any game is about event loops.

So to structure your game:

1. Have a module representing the game loader loop, which renders the GUI of those buttons. A good practice is to have most (or even all, really) GUI rendering outside and before the event loop, then have the event loop + bunch of if-else statements to listen to button clicks.
2. Have each button click represents a specific event, and delegates what would happen after clicking each button to separate functions, which take on the duty of importing and loading the specific game modules (other .py's).
3. You could alternate the behavior of the main window so the game loader GUI is gone and the specific game takes and reuses it, or simply spawn another window for the specific game.
4. [Alt to 2] You can place your actual game logics in different threads within a single module which also hosts the game loader loop. Use this way properly could result in a more responsive overall game experience (e.g switching out of a game would go back to the other thread that runs the game loader loop while it's still hot in memory)

A poor illustration of how this could be done:

```
import pygame
import game_module_one  # your game logic
# two, three, four...

# Your game loader
def main():
    # Initialise window
    pygame.init()
    window = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768))
    # Bunch of rendering jobs, set fonts, draw buttons, etc.

    # Event loop
    while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                return
            elif event.type == "start_game_one":
                do_game_one(window)
            #...

# Game one loading function
def do_game_one(window):
    # do something to that window if you intend to
    pygame.display.flip()
    game_one_module.start()
```

Consider the [reference](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/) on mouse, event, display and surface

Hope this helps.

Comment: firstly, thank you very much for your help.
where you have called game_one_module, would that be able to use input from the GUI? or more importantly, would input on the GUI be able to trigger different functions in that game module and pass it parameters?

Comment: So you have all rendering and image loading in one thread, while event handling in the other?

Comment: you can use input from the GUI if you take control over it. The reference on display and surface should be sufficient, play around with Surface object and have a feeling yourself.

@monkey oh no, I meant the game loader (the mere main() sample) logic could be in one thread, while actual game logics could be in their separate threads.